# SharePoint 2013 , the user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: 2013, people-picker, user, unique

I'm having the following error when trying to submit the form and assigning the task through people/group picker field

Note: The user account is not locked in AD + I tried multiple users but it gives me the same error msg.

Error :
The form cannot be submitted.
The user does not exist or is not unique.

Comment: is it out of the box or custom form, what is type of the field, is the issue limited to just this list or people picker is not working in other lists as well.

Comment: It is a custom form and the field is people picker. This issue is limited to this list and I've tried with many users in AD and the same msg shown to me. @MarekSarad

Comment: When you mean custom, is this SP Designer custom form or Infopath custom form?